# Error converting data type varchar to numeric while updating column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

```
update policy
    set EstimatedPremium =  cast(etl.estpremium as Numeric(19,4)) 
    from policy p join
         etlpolicy etl
         on p.policynumber = etl.policynumber
```

I am trying to update a column in one table `policy` from another column in table `etlpolicy`. In the destination column the data type is Numeric(19,4), and the source column is varchar(20).

I get the message:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your query not work?

Comment: varchar2 is an oracle datatype, not SQL Server?

Comment: It is varachar(20) not it it giving same Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, except for the `update`.  You need to use the table alias:

```
update p
-------^
    set EstimatedPremium =  cast(etl.estpremium as Numeric(19,4)) 
    from policy p join
         etlpolicy etl
         on p.policynumber = etl.policynumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the values on the second table (etlpolicy) are all convertible to numeric?

Also: Are they using the correct decimal separator according to your culture?
For instance: "1.950,00" may complicate things depending on your environment.

You can:

```
select cast(etl.estpremium as Numeric(19, 4)) prm
from etlpolicy etl
```

Or even, I believe SQL Server has the IsNumeric function (I haven't tested):

```
select IsNumeric(etl.estpremium) prm, etl.estpremium
from etlpolicy etl
```

And it should return 0 for non-numeric values.

Comment: yes the second one is working IsNumeric, it is returning values, But how can I update that values to policytable

Comment: Can you try `cast(etl.estpremium as float)`?

Comment: ... as in `update p set EstimatedPremium = cast(etl.estpremium as float) ...`

Comment: it says Error converting data type varchar to float

Comment: In the first query that I sent you: `select cast(etl.estpremium as Numeric(19, 4)) prm from etlpolicy etl` does it work?

Comment: Because it does look like you have a string value that is not numeric. Are there any null values maybe?